# Update values on properties file on Runtime

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, properties-file

I've configuration as below:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Profile("local")
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("path/to/resources/app-local.properties"));
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

My `app-local.properties` file contains values as:

```
cache.time.milliseconds=1000
```

So, I'm accessing the value as:

```
    @Value("${cache.time.milliseconds}")
    private long cachingTime;
```

I'm getting the correct value.

```
System.out.println(cachingTime);
```

Now, I want to update the `cachingTime` to some other value and serve that updated value. For example, from 1000 to 99.

Is there any way to update this property value at runtime??

Or is there any other way to update this value except restarting app or server?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE.

I tried to google it, but none of answer gave me the solution. :(

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you will change the value on property file it will not effect on runtime because all the configuration is done while server starting, if you don't want to redeploy the code base you can do one thing, change the property file value and just restart the server.

Comment: I know that... but my requirement is I should not be restarting server or app. :)

Comment: There is no other option

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at spring-boot admin once. Though it acts as a monitoring server, it gives you ability to update properties and environment variables.

http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.5.3/

Attaching a screenshot put up a proof of concept by codecentric guys.

[image]